# Object has no method 'focus' in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onfocus

I have input in HTML-page:

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" tabindex="0" type="text" value="Name:" />
```

I wrote javascript with jQuery to bind handlers for events "onfocus" and "onblur":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = $("#Name");
    name.focus(function () {if ($(this).val() == "Name:") $(this).val('');});
    name.blur(function () {if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val("Name:");});
</script>
```

So, when user chooses input, it's value should become empty. If user doesn't enter text in input and change focus, input's value returns to 'Name:'.

It works fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera, but it doesn't work in Google Chrome. Furthemore, there is error in chrome debugger: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'focus'".

How can I bind handlers with jQuery in Google Chrome?
Thanks!

Comment: is the script tag after the input tag? Is there any other element on the page with an id="Name"?

Comment: It works for me with Chrome 22 on OS X.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nccq5/. Are you including it inside a document.ready call?

Comment: Bug has been detected in Google Chrome 21 in Win XP and Win 7.

Comment: Script tag is after input tag. There is unique element with id="Name" on the page.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to use something different instead of "Name". For example "MyName". And, please, answer, if that helped.

Comment: Script is not included in document.ready call. It places in the end of html before </body>

Comment: I changed id to id="Author" and rewrote script accordingly. Problem remained.

Comment: Simple js works fine. I mean something like `document.getElementById("Author").onfocus = function () { ... }` But what's problem with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow Chrome doesn't like your variable to be named "name" in this case. The following works

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var name2 = $("#Name"); 
    name2.focus(function () {if ($(this).val() == "Name:") $(this).val('');}); 
    name2.blur(function () {if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val("Name:");}); 
</script>
```